# Count Column in C# with join

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to count my ReviewDetails.Review column but i got error:

> Column 'AdvertiserMaster.AdvertiserID' is invalid in the select list 
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the 
>   GROUP BY clause.

Here Is My Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
AdvertiserMaster.AdvertiserID, AdvertiserMaster.BusinessName , ISNULL(AdvertiserMaster.AverageRating, 0) AS AverageRating, AdvertiserMaster.ImageURL1, AdvertiserMaster.Address1, 
AdvertiserMaster.CategoryID, AdvertiserMaster.Email, AdvertiserMaster.CountryID, AdvertiserMaster.StateID, AdvertiserMaster.CityID, AdvertiserMaster.PinCode, AdvertiserMaster.Mobile, 
CategoryMaster.CategoryName, CountryMaster.CountryName, StateMaster.StateName, CityMaster.CityName,Count(ReviewDetails.Review) AS ReviewCount
FROM AdvertiserMaster INNER JOIN
BusinessCategoryDetails ON AdvertiserMaster.AdvertiserID = BusinessCategoryDetails.AdvertiserID INNER JOIN
ReviewDetails ON AdvertiserMaster.AdvertiserID = ReviewDetails.AdvertiserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
CategoryMaster ON AdvertiserMaster.CategoryID = CategoryMaster.CategoryID LEFT OUTER JOIN
CountryMaster ON AdvertiserMaster.CountryID = CountryMaster.CountryID LEFT OUTER JOIN
CityMaster ON AdvertiserMaster.CityID = CityMaster.CityID LEFT OUTER JOIN
StateMaster ON AdvertiserMaster.StateID = StateMaster.StateID LEFT OUTER JOIN
SubCategoryMaster ON BusinessCategoryDetails.SubCategoryID = SubCategoryMaster.SubCategoryID
WHERE (AdvertiserMaster.CategoryID = 8) AND (AdvertiserMaster.CityID = 16619) AND (AdvertiserMaster.IsActive = 1)
```

Since I am trying to get count by writing Count(ReviewDetails.Review)

But it is of no use.

here is my tables:[ClassifiedBD Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlC9v.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count something (or use other aggregate functions like sum), you need to define the level on which you count with group by clause, for example like this:

```
SELECT
  AdvertiserMaster.AdvertiserID,
  AdvertiserMaster.BusinessName,
  ISNULL(AdvertiserMaster.AverageRating, 0) AS AverageRating,
  AdvertiserMaster.ImageURL1,
  AdvertiserMaster.Address1,
  AdvertiserMaster.CategoryID,
  AdvertiserMaster.Email,
  AdvertiserMaster.CountryID,
  AdvertiserMaster.StateID,
  AdvertiserMaster.CityID,
  AdvertiserMaster.PinCode,
  AdvertiserMaster.Mobile,
  CategoryMaster.CategoryName,
  CountryMaster.CountryName,
  StateMaster.StateName,
  CityMaster.CityName,
  COUNT(ReviewDetails.Review) AS ReviewCount
FROM AdvertiserMaster
INNER JOIN BusinessCategoryDetails
  ON AdvertiserMaster.AdvertiserID = BusinessCategoryDetails.AdvertiserID
INNER JOIN ReviewDetails
  ON AdvertiserMaster.AdvertiserID = ReviewDetails.AdvertiserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CategoryMaster
  ON AdvertiserMaster.CategoryID = CategoryMaster.CategoryID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CountryMaster
  ON AdvertiserMaster.CountryID = CountryMaster.CountryID
LEFT OUTER JOIN CityMaster
  ON AdvertiserMaster.CityID = CityMaster.CityID
LEFT OUTER JOIN StateMaster
  ON AdvertiserMaster.StateID = StateMaster.StateID
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubCategoryMaster
  ON BusinessCategoryDetails.SubCategoryID = SubCategoryMaster.SubCategoryID
WHERE (AdvertiserMaster.CategoryID = 8)
AND (AdvertiserMaster.CityID = 16619)
AND (AdvertiserMaster.IsActive = 1)
GROUP BY AdvertiserMaster.AdvertiserID,
         AdvertiserMaster.BusinessName,
         ISNULL(AdvertiserMaster.AverageRating, 0),
         AdvertiserMaster.ImageURL1,
         AdvertiserMaster.Address1,
         AdvertiserMaster.CategoryID,
         AdvertiserMaster.Email,
         AdvertiserMaster.CountryID,
         AdvertiserMaster.StateID,
         AdvertiserMaster.CityID,
         AdvertiserMaster.PinCode,
         AdvertiserMaster.Mobile,
         CategoryMaster.CategoryName,
         CountryMaster.CountryName,
         StateMaster.StateName,
         CityMaster.CityName
```

You don't need distinct when you have group by.

You also might want to start using aliases for the tables and formatting / indenting your SQL properly